# Groovy extracts value from xml file

Tags: xml, groovy

i have `soapui` and I'm trying to extract the value false from a XML file.

**responseCurrentDate.xml**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="https://alo.io/ns/20130518">
   <soap:Body>
      <log_resp>
         <alo_env>
            <cid>K06BZQ6476WHP5ZFWW0NEJC937GB</cid>
            <result>ALO_OK</result>
         </alo_env>
         <item>
            <response>{"timestamp": "2015-11-12T03:02:45Z", "data": null, "success": false, "error": {"message": "{'desc': \"Can't contact LDAP server\"}", "code": 500, "label": "Internal Server Error"}}</response>
         </item>
      </log_resp>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried this with groovy

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )

def date = new Date()
def dts = date.format("yyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")

def myOutFile = "C:/temp2/response"+dts+".xml"
def response = context.expand('${login#Response}')
def f = new File(myOutFile)
f.write(response, "UTF-8")

def xmlfile = myOutFile 
def x = new XmlParser(),parseText(myOutFile)
println it.response.item.success
```

I got his error:

> org.xml.sax,SAXException.lineNumber1mcolumnNumber1,Content is not allowed in Prolog

Comment: Why are you writing it to a file, then calling parse text on the file? Just call parseText on response

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by  tim_yates, don't save the xml content in a file, just use parseText with `response`:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )

def date = new Date()
def dts = date.format("yyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")

def response = context.expand('${login#Response}')
def x = new XmlParser().parseText(response)
```

But, if you really need to save the content in a file, than use `parse` instead of `parseText` and with a `File` instance, not with a string which contains the file name:

```
def f = new File(myOutFile)
f.write(response, "UTF-8")    
def x = new XmlParser().parse(f)
```

Comment: thank you Tommaso Di Bucchianico and tim yates , it works but i cannot the specific value from the response so that s why i wanted to save the response in a file and the search the specific value, maybe i have to save the file as txt, i don't know